# Specific equilateral triangle given two points in 3D

Tags: geometry, triangles, 3d

Let's say I have two points: $A = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $B = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$.

How can I find a third point $C = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$ such that:
a) $A$, $B$ & $C$ form an equilateral triangle
b) the value of $z_2$ is the highest it can be

Thanks a lot for your time :)

***I've tried some examples with pre-set points, forming non-linear systems of equations $AC$, $BC$, $DC$ ($D$ being the midpoint of $AB$) and then doing some partial derivatives on these results. I got what I was looking for for some specific example (where $z_0 = z_1 = 0$) but am sort of doing it headlessly until I get what I want and that hasn't worked out for me for more complicated examples (like when $z_0\ne z_1$).***

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting to mathematical expressions. See  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thanks I fixed it

Comment: What $C$ do you expect to get when $z_0\ne z_1$ 
but $x_0=x_1$ and $y_0=y_1$?
In this case $z_2=\tfrac12(z_0+z_1)$,
but what about $x_2$ and $y_2$?

Comment: haha yeah really good question. In my scenario, this will actually never happen, two points will never have the same $x$ and $y$

Comment: but yeah even though it won't happen, if it's easier to include it we could just say that any correct $x_2$/$y_2$ combination would do

Comment: You have two spheres that intersect - based on the distance between A and B. Than you could use derivatives to solve the equation for z maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

[image]

Special cases aside,
let $A_z>B_z$. Consider the point $D=(x_1,y_1,z_0)$.
$\triangle ADB$ defines the plane where the sought point $C$ would be located.
Use cross-product of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{DB}$ to rotate $A$ by $60^\circ$ around $B$.

---

**Edit**

For example, in terms of
a powerful descriptive vector graphics language
[Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) it would be just

```
triple C=rotate(60,B,B+cross(A-B,D-B))*A;
```

Comment: thank you so much! :)

Comment: Would you mind giving me a little bit more information on how to put the last sentence into action? Thanks a lot

Comment: @MXu: see updated answer.

Comment: Sorry to push it further but I'm quite unfamiliar with this programming language :( Would you mind turning this into python code or just a formula? Once again, thank you so much for all the help :)

Comment: Using Rodrigues' rotation formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) would k be the unit cross(AB, DB) vector, v the AB vector and $\theta$ = 60 degrees?

Comment: @MXu:That's exactly right, in this case  
$k$ is the unit $\vec{AB}\times \vec{DB}$ vector, 
$v$ is the $\vec{AB}$ vector and $\theta= 60^\circ$.

Comment: Well, thank you so much for everything, for helping me, and I'm guessing many others, with our problems. My field of study is not very popular right now but you've inspired me to try and do the same. Have a great day/night!

Comment: @MXu: Thanks. Just in case: the Rodrigues' rotation formula
gives the rotated vector $\vec{v_{\mathrm{rot}}}$. 
The location of the point $C=B+\vec{v_{\mathrm{rot}}}$.   
And if you are going to dig into 3D/math,
consider to give the `Asymptote` a try, together with `TeXLive`
(if you don't have it already).